# Regex replace special characters defind by client

Tags: c#, regex

I need a c# function which will replace all special characters customized by the client from a string Example

```
 string value1 = @"‹¥ó×¬¶ÝÆ";
 string input1 = @"Thi¥s is\123a strÆing";
 string output1 = Regex.Replace(input1, value1, "");
```

I want have a result like this : `output1 =Thi s is\123a str ing`

Comment: What do you mean by "special character"? All non-ASCII characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone asked for a regex?

```
string value1 = @"^\-[]‹¥ó×¬¶ÝÆ";
string input1 = @"T-^\hi¥s is\123a strÆing";

// Handles ]^-\ by escaping them
string value1b = Regex.Replace(value1, @"([\]\^\-\\])", @"\$1");

// Creates a [...] regex and uses it
string input1b = Regex.Replace(input1, "[" + value1b + "]", " ");
```

The basic idea is to use a `[...]` regex. But first you have to escape some characters that have special meaning inside a `[...]`. They should be `]^-\` Note that you don't need to escape the `[`

**note that this solution isn't compatible with non-BMP unicode characters (characters that fill-up two `char`)**
A solution that is compatible with them is more complex, but for normal use it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Why not just use `Regex.Escape`?

Comment: @juharr Doesn't escape some charaters, like `-` and `]`. It should be used for text "outside" a `[]`

Comment: thanks very match Mr. xanatos,this proposal help me :)

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need regex? This is more efficient, concise also readable:

```
string result = string.Concat(input1.Except(value1));
```

If you don't want to remove but replace them with a different `string` you can still use  a similar(but not as efficient) approach:

```
string replacement = "[foo]";
var newChars = input1.SelectMany(c => value1.Contains(c) ? replacement : c.ToString());
string result = string.Concat( newChars ); // Thi[foo]s is\123a str[foo]ing
```

Comment: @fubo: but he also uses `""` as replacement.

Comment: For replacement it would just require `Join` and `Split` instead of `Concat` and `Except`  like `string.Join(replacement, input1.Split(value1.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.None))`

Comment: @fubo: point taken, i have provided a similar approach that is not that efficient but allows to replace all characters with any string you want.